# Como calcular la siguiente serie con c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio en C#

Calcular la siguiente serie

```
1 + x + x + x3 + x2 + x5 + x3 + x7
```

Donde `n` es el número de veces que se repetirá la serie y `x` es un valor real positivo. Ambos valores se leen.

Ejemplo

```
n=4 y x=1.1

Resultado 9.84
```

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
double exp = 0.0;
double suma = 0;
int cont = 0;

do{
  suma += Math.Pow(x, exp) + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, exp * 2 + 1));
  exp++;
  cont++;
}while(cont < n);
```

Con ese código al resultado le falta decimales de acuerdo a lo que se muestra en el ejemplo, que tengo mal o que me falta agregar??

Comment: Intenta con `suma+= Math.Pow(x, exp) + (x * (exp * 2 + 1));`

Comment: @alanfcm, no funcionó,  modifique a como dijiste y da un resultado alto

Comment: Pero es que el resultado es incorrecto, debería dar `10,631227100000002`

Comment: @Yussef te refieres al resultado que pongo de ejemplo??

Comment: si yo hago esto: `double x = 1.1; double result=1 + x + x + Math.Pow(x,3) + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(x, 5) + Math.Pow(x, 3) + Math.Pow(x, 7);` el resultado es que te indico arriba

Comment: @Yussef tienes razón pero lamentablemente no es la respuesta que se da en el ejemplo

Comment: @JorgeAlonso No entiendo tu respuesta, ese es el resultado no hay más. O está incorrecta la serie, o los valores iniciales no son eso, pero hay algo incorrecto en lo que planteas

Comment: @Yussef todo eso lo plantea una maestra, yo también pienso que hay error en el planteamiento del problema o en el ejemplo que está dando

Comment: Puedes colocar exactamente el enunciado del problema?

Comment: @Yussef como puse el enunciado es como lo puso la maestra

Comment: Bueno eso está incorrecto y no hay más vuelta que darle, si tu sacas la raíz cuadrada de tu código te da el resultado correcto (supongo que la has colocado para calzar a la fuerza el resultado esperado, pero sobra y no se condice con la serie). Entonces, tú ya tiene el código correcto y no existe forma de responder tu pregunta, por lo que te invito a que la borres. Por mi parte votaré para cerrarla

Comment: Qué es x2, x3, x4... no se explica de dónde salen estos valores. Se piden, o cómo se calculan?

Comment: Los profesores son humanos y pueden cometer errores. Mándale un mensaje privado, o un correo electrónico y le explicas tus hallazgos. Si algún día doy clases de programación, el primer día de clases les dejaré claro que 1- No lo sé todo, 2- Puedo equivocarme, 3- Agradeceré me corrijan cuando esto ocurra.